# Possible to manipulate javascript generated elements?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, object

I have a page dynamically generated with javascript and it contains several input fields and a button.  When I click the button, nothing happens...Is it because it is a javascript object and not a "real" dom object?  If so, is there a way to interact with the object?

I just wrote a simple alert to see if the button is even working.

```
jQuery("#button").click(function() {
   alert("yes it's working");
});
```

On first page load this works...I believe on first page load it is PHP generated and when I click to another section, this same button will show up BUT the page does not refresh so this leads me to believe when I click on to another section, it is dynamically re-generated with JS.

Now if I click the button, nothing happens...no errors or no alerts...

Comment: Can you show your code? You have to specify what should happen if you click the button. If you create the elements correctly, they are "real" DOM objects.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show some code. In general, all DOM objects are equal, no matter whether they come from HTML source code, or Javascript.

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is supposed to happen? Give a sample of what is generated, and what you expect from this generated HTML. Your generated HTML should behave just like non-generated HTML, assuming it is properly generated.

Comment: JavaScript generated elements go in the same DOM as all else, so there is no difference. Some code will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys for the super fast response, i have edited my question to better illustrate the issue

Comment: Is your button generated before the behaviors are applied to it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.live` because at the point in time when you assign the handler the element doesn't exist.

```
$('#button').live('click', function() {
});
```

You should also look into delegate if you're doing this with multiple elements for efficiency purposes.

Comment: why didn't i think of that...I will use livequery since i have that loaded already...thanks that was the reason!!

Answer (score 2):

I think I get what you're saying.

When you run `jQuery('#button')`, it searches for the elements then and there. The event is attached to the button itself, not to the query string `#button`.

jQuery does, however, offer the behavior you want.

```
jQuery('#button').live('click', function () { /* on click event */ });
```

`live` attaches to the query string, not the elements, so it will apply to any `#button` ever generated in the future.

Comment: why didn't i think of that...I will use livequery since i have that loaded already...thanks that was the reason!!

Comment: @Rick - note that newer versions of jQuery have `live` built in, and don't require a plugin :)

Comment: Oh really?  Thanks a bunch...I will use live then...When you say newer, as in 1.4.2 and up? or all 1.4+?

Comment: @Rick - it's been around for a while now, [apparently since 1.3](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: @Rick: Please also note that an ID has to be unique. You cannot have have multiple buttons with ID `button`.

Comment: @Felix Kling - I suspect that he's replacing the entire page, so I didn't mention... but yeah, that's worth noting, just in case :)